# How to remove the date information in a column, just keep time

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas dataframe. there is a specific column has time information.

the raw data likes this:

```
5:15am
5:28am
6:15am
```

so I need to convert the raw data into datetime format:

```
format = '%I:%M%p'
dataset['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['TimeStamp'],format)
```

However, I got:

```
2014-07-04 05:15:00
2014-07-04 05:28:00
2014-07-04 06:15:00
```

I don't want the year and date information, just want time. How can I remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following will convert what you have to datetime.time() objects:

```
dataset['TimeStamp'] = pd.Series([val.time() for val in dataset['TimeStamp']])
```

Output

```
  TimeStamp
0  05:15:00
1  05:28:00
2  06:15:00
```

Comment: better to do ``pd.DatetimeIndex(dateset['TimeStamp']).time`` same results though

Comment: @Jeff, thanks. This worked for me, not the accepted solution.

Comment: it turns out I wanted `val.date()` the answer gave me the inspiration :)

Answer (score 17):

Since version `0.17.0` you can just do

```
dataset['TimeStamp'].dt.time
```

For versions older than `0.17.0`:

You can just call `apply` and access the `time` function on the datetime object create the column initially like this without the need for post processing:

```
In [143]:

dataset['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['TimeStamp'],format).apply(lambda x: x.time())
dataset
Out[143]:
  TimeStamp
0  05:15:00
1  05:28:00
2  06:15:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [`datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) function

> datetime.time()
>   Return time object with same hour, minute, second and microsecond. tzinfo is None. See also method timetz().

This will return a `datetime.time` object and you can access the data with the `time.hour` `time.minute` and `time.second` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

## `your_date_df.dt.time`

Lets say that your column with the date ans time is `df['arrived_date']`:

```
0   2015-01-06 00:43:00
1   2015-01-06 07:56:00
2   2015-01-06 11:02:00
3   2015-01-06 11:22:00
4   2015-01-06 15:27:00
Name: arrived_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Whith pandas, you just need to do:

```
df['arrived_time']=df['arrived_date'].dt.time
```

The new column `df['arrived_time']` will look like this:

```
0    00:43:00
1    07:56:00
2    11:02:00
3    11:22:00
4    15:27:00
Name: arrived_time, dtype: object
```

#### **Observe** that the new column, `df['arrived_time']`, is no longer a `datetime64` type, the type of the column is just a pandas `object`

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way to do it using pandas, although most, if not all solutions are correct

```
df.TimeStamp = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Answer (score -2):

dataset['TimeStamp']=dataset['TimeStamp'].str.slice(11,18)