# Select a time range in DataFrame without date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm using/learning `Pandas` to load a csv style dataset where I have a time column that can be used as index. The data is sampled roughly at 100Hz. Here is a simplified snippet of the data:

`Time (sec)  Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
0.0100      14.175  -29.97  -22.68 
0.0200      13.905  -29.835 -22.68
0.0300      12.257  -29.32  -22.67
... ...
1259.98     -0.405   2.205   3.825
1259.99     -0.495   2.115   3.735`

There are 20 min of data, resulting in about 120,000 rows at 100 Hz. My goal is to select those rows within a certain time range, say 100-200 sec.

Here is what I've figured out

```
import panda as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)                    # my_data is a numpy array
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s', origin='1900-1-1')  # the date in origin is just a space-holder
```

My dataset doesn't include the date. How to avoid setting a fake date like I did above? It feels wrong, and also is quite annoying when I plot the data against time.

I know there are ways to remove date from the datatime object like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567078/how-to-remove-the-date-information-in-a-column-just-keep-time).
But my goal is to select some rows that are in a certain time range, which means I need to use `pd.date_range()`. This function does not seem to work without date.

It's not the end of the world if I just use a fake date throughout my project. But I'd like to know if there are more elegant ways around it.

Comment: Could you iterate through something like: `range(0, df['Time (sec)'].max(), 200)`?

Comment: @pshep123 yes i could... I've actually implemented the said features by manipulations in the original numpy array. Yet after realizing what panda can do, i thought my data is a perfect candidate to use panda because it's nicely structured and has a time index, so I decided to give it a try. I thought it'd be a piece of cake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need to use `datetime64` objects for this. Your time column is an number, so you can very easily select time intervals with inequalities. You can also plot the columns without issue.

### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(0,1200,0.01),
                   'Col_A': np.random.randint(1,100,120000),
                   'Col_B': np.random.randint(1,10,120000)})
```

---

#### Select Data between 100 and 200 seconds.

```
df[df.Time.between(100,200)]
```

Outputs:

```
         Time  Col_A  Col_B
10000  100.00     75      9
10001  100.01     23      7
...
19999  199.99     39      7
20000  200.00     25      2
```

---

#### Plotting against time

```
#First 100 rows just for illustration
df[0:100].plot(x='Time')
```

[image]

---

#### Convert to `timedelta64`

If you really wanted to, you could convert the column to a `timedelta64[ns]`

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='s') - pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')

print(df.head())
#             Time  Col_A  Col_B
#0        00:00:00     67      6
#1 00:00:00.010000     93      1
#2 00:00:00.020000     99      3
#3 00:00:00.030000     18      2
#4 00:00:00.040000     84      3

df.dtypes
#Time     timedelta64[ns]
#Col_A              int32
#Col_B              int32
#dtype: object
```

Comment: Ah ha! I didn't know this trick `df[df.Time.between(100,200)]`. This is my first time using pandas. Thanks! Your answer is very nicely presented.